# Work done compressing air in a hand pump, inconsistency with physical work done

Tags: thermodynamics

If I compress air (say a liter of air to 1/3 of its volume) isothermally using a hand pump 
the work done would be 113.5J, at a temperature of 300K and with R for air 0.344J/K/litre. This is using the relation nRTln(P2/P1). Whereas the true mechanical work done considering the differential pressure with
respect to atmospheric pressure will be the net average force exerted by the compressed airX displacement of the piston viz. (3-1)/2*1.013E5*A*(2/3)*d
    =1.013E5 * 1E-3*2/3= 67.5J

It appears that we need to do lesser work to compress the air by using handpump taking into consideration of atmospheric pressure.
What is wrong in the calculations!

Comment: Are you sure the average pressure over time is (3-1)/2?

Comment: In the second case, you should be evaluating the average pressure by using the value of the pressure at the logarithmic mean volume.

Comment: The log-mean volume is 0.607 liters, and the pressure evaluated at this volume is 1.65 bars.  Both calculations then give a value of 111.2 Joules for the work.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that this is the work done on the system only if the compression is done reversibly.  Otherwise the amount of work will be greater than this.

Comment: I would not be able to accept any of the above proposed solutions, b'coz if I consider for the case of compression ratio of say 1:2, the isothermal compression of air would consume 0.344*300*1*ln(2)=71.5J whereas even
if I assume 2atm pressure opposing the piston throughout the compression process(but that is not the case clearly), the external mechanical work would be:
(2-1)* 1.013E5*A*d*1/2 = 50.7J that is still 25% less than the isothermal work involved! So where is the difference. I have subtracted atmospheric pressure to calculate the net force at any time in the compression of air.